Highly available wireguard gateway in kubernetes
Is it possible to create a deployment of wireguard pods which will be exposed via a service, and then route data from other containers through it.
I created a wireguard deployment and exposed it through a cluster IP service, but I can't get other containers to route data through the cluster IP as it is not reachable. However, I can route through the endpoints of the cluster IP (the IPs of the wireguard containers).
My main aim is to connect 2 kubernetes clusters, through a wireguard VPN which contains multiple wireguard servers per cluster for HA & load distribution.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

If you want to connect multiple kubernetes using the WireGuard effectively you can follow the below approches,

Peer configuration : Each wireGuard server should be configured with the peers (the other wireGuard servers) it will connect to. Each peer configuration includes,
Publickey : The public key of the peer.
Endpoint  : The IP and port of the peer.
AllowedIP’s : Specifies which IP’s are routed through this peer.


Refer to this for a step by step process.
Multiple 'servers' can have the same keypairs defined in the config. You can use domain names in the wireguard config.

Keep Alive and MTU settings: Set the appropriate keep-alive and MTU settings to ensure availability.

Note : Ensure each container that needs to route traffic through the VPN has the correct routing table setup.

Thank you for your response Imran. I am able to set up the wireguard servers without any issues, but had issues with the route table of the containers that need to use the VPN. After some research, I am leaning towards using ECMP on the containers to route traffic to the wireguard servers.

I am glad the issue has been resolved.What should I do when someone answers my question?
